# Connect Headphones to phone

Tags: telephone

Using standard headphones, is it possible to connect it to a standard non-VOIP wired phone?  What connector would I need, or how could I rewire this?

Headphones have some kind of 3.5 mm jack, Phone handsets have 4 wires BRGY going into a jack.  But that's all I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step in researching this kind of project is to look for the pinout.

[image]

Then you can check what a common headset plug might be (there are different pinouts, you'll need to test yours, especially for an Apple product):

[image]

Then you might think, someone must have done this before, so you google the final product and get this kind of thing:

[image]

So, you can build it by buying the proper 2.5mm female jack and wiring it in to the handset plug, or you can buy the finished product for around $15.

Comment: Except the position of mic ring and ground can be swapped on some products http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-phone-8-how-guides/249287-note-headset-standards-omtp-ahj-apple.html

Comment: @RespawnedFluff It's not an exception to what I said, because what I said was "there are different pinouts, you'll need to test yours".

Comment: Indeed. Alas, I've only skimmed what you wrote, expecting to see the two usual configs in the diagram, not just one.